# Who was "Toody Hotpot"?

Tags: expressions, slang

My late mother (born in the 1920s in London, where she lived all her life) was fond of saying of anyone who wasn't helping in any particular job or activity that they were ***"Just standing around, like Toody Hotpot"***.

I've no idea if that spelling is correct: I doubt if she ever wrote the phrase down or had any need to do so, and even if she did I certainly never saw the result.

I regret never asking her where the expression came from, and subsequent research has failed to turn up any hints.  Does anyone here know?  Many thanks.

Comment: Where did your mother live?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said.  She was born, raised, and lived all her life in London.

Comment: I'm guessing that's not the correct spelling.

Comment: Very possibly not.  I doubt if she ever wrote the phrase down, and if she did I certainly never saw the result.  Do you have a suggestion for an alternative spelling?

Comment: @BertCoules If she was a Londoner, my guess is that it is rhyming slang for something, but I can't think what it could possibly be.

Comment: WS2, thanks for the thought.  She was a Londoner but not an East Londoner.  My father and his parents _were_ from the East End and I never heard any of them use the phrase.  And like you, I can't come up with a convincing rhyming (or even part-rhyming) meaning.

Comment: @BertCoules I've searched on a rhyming slang site but nothing comes up. Do you think it was spelled 'toady hotpot'. Now if a hotpot (stew) was made from dead toads, I guess it would 'stand around' for a long while wouldn't it. Can't imagine anyone wanting to eat it, can you? I have never heard it before and there appears nothing on the web. But I would be almost willing to bet that is where it comes from.

Comment: Try it out on one of the other more senior UK contributors to the site  e.g. @Edwin Ashworth. He may know of it.

Comment: WS2, that's a fascinating notion, and while I'm quite certain that she pronounced the first word as _Toody_ I suppose it could have been corrupted over the years in its passage down the family.  How, apart from posting the question as I have done, could I go about putting it to any more senior contributors?

Comment: I wonder if "hotpot" isn't simply a pot of stew, and maybe the phrase is "today's hotpot" -- a pot of stew sitting there passively waiting for people to serve themselves.  Or something of that ilk.

Answer (score 2):

The Concise New Partridge Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English mentions "**hot toddy**" as rhyming slang for "the body" ([Google Books](https://books.google.es/books?id=GIuEAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA345&lpg=PA345&dq=Toody%20Hotpot%20rhyming%20slang&source=bl&ots=3n_MUZTmCB&sig=pYUIwVd5wSjOANiJYOou_Z3mgl8&hl=es&sa=X&ei=i9jTVM6aOcy6Ub_xg6gC&ved=0CDkQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=Toody%20Hotpot&f=false)).

As BertCoules admits, "Toddy Hotpot" could well be a corruption over time. Bert's mother's expression could refer to a dead body, a still body that will not help in her task.

Comment: Note that _hot toddy_ in that dictionary is dated to 1992, which is very late if it had been in oral use for over a century.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - But certainly "hot toddy", as the name of a beverage, has been around since before I was born (and that was a long time ago).

Comment: @HotLicks Certainly! Though I rather fancy (my own extreme dislike of the concoction notwithstanding) that hot toddy is—or, especially, used to be—quite a popular drink. Not one you’d generally associate with being allowed to just stand there for long without being swooped up and drunk. So without the rhyming slang angle, it doesn’t seem a very good candidate for the meaning in question.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - But it's unclear how one gets from "Toody Hotpot" to "Hot Toddy" anyway.

Comment: RicardoGMC, belated thanks for that.  But as has been said, it was definitely "Toody" rather than "Toddy" which, especially when considered with the other dissimilarities, seems to me to make a simple corruption unlikely.